# Using a new thread to post to observers

Tags: java, multithreading, android, observer-pattern

I have implemented my own Observer pattern. I want to post my events in a new thread. This thread would simply call all the the observers/listeners with the posted event.

```
public class EventManager
{
    private ArrayList<Observer> observerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void post(Object event)
    {
       new Thread(new MyRunnable(this, event)).start();
    }

    public void postHelper(Object event)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < observerList.size(); i++)
        {
            Observer observer = observerList.get(i);
            observer.handle(event);
        }
    }


    private static class MyRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        EventManager eventManager;
        Object event;

        public MyRunnable(EventManager eventManager, Object e)
        {
            this.eventManager = eventManager;
            event = e;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            eventManager.postHelper(event); 
        }
    }
}

public interface Observer
{
    void handle(Object event);
}
```

How can I improve this? My main concern is that I am creating a thread everytime, which could potentially leave me out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for editing. It would make an even better post if you included some example usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of threads you're using via a thread pool. For example:

```
public class EventManager { 
    private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
    [....]
```

and then use it like so:

```
pool.execute(new MyRunnable(this, event));
```

You should also take care of shutting down the pool when/if you dispose the EventManager.
For further information check the [API docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html%22different%20kinds%22) (Android in your case).

Comment: Two questions. 1) Will the ExecutorService know when the thread finishes and re-add make that thread available for the next event?  2) What happens if I execute all the threads in the pool, will the events get queued?

Comment: 1) Yes, you can also choose among different implementations of it (e.g. ScheduledExecutorService, ForkJoinPool, etc...)
2) Yes. From the docs: _Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation._